# typeorm one-on-one entity not found on getManager.find

Tags: node.js, nestjs, typeorm

I have this typeorm entity:

```
@Entity({ name: 'trans' })
export class Transaction {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn({ type: 'int', name: 'trans_id' })
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(type => Credit, credit => credit.transaction, { cascade: true })
  credit: Credit
}
```

With the following relation:

```
@Entity({ name: 'trans_credit' })
export class Credit {
  @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'int', name: 'trans_id' })
  id: number;
  
  @OneToOne(type => Transaction, transaction => transaction.credit)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'trans_id' })
  transaction: Transaction;
}
```

There is no FK defined on the trans_credit table. Corresponding tables are:

```
CREATE TABLE `trans` (`trans_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT) AUTO_INCREMENT=1
CREATE TABLE `trans_credit` (`trans_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL)
```

All entities and table declarations presented here are simplified of course.

When I try to query:

```
const fromEntity = getRepository(Transaction).find({
            where: [
                { status: 'pending', credit: { j5: 1 } }
            ]
        });
```

I get this:

```
Error: Relation with property path trans_id in entity was not found
```

**Why oh why is this happening?**

Answer (score 0):

You specified your `id` column name of `Credit` as `trans_id`. And you defined the name of `JoinColumn` as `trans_id` too.

I think `trans_id` should be `credit_id` in your case:

```js
@Entity({ name: 'trans_credit' })
export class Credit {
  @PrimaryColumn({ type: 'int', name: 'credit_id' }) // <- updated the column name
  id: number;
  
  @OneToOne(type => Transaction, transaction => transaction.credit)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'trans_id' })
  transaction: Transaction;
}
```

Comment: I understand why you would suppose that, but in this case Credit has trans_id as its id and PK, rather than credit_id.

Comment: PS: I also tried defining the 'transaction' relation as both PrimaryColumn and JoinColumn on top of OneToOne (discarding the 'id' field), but that didn't do the trick either.